# Git squash commit or change commit description without using force

Tags: git

I have a repository where I am not allowed to use force. Unfortunately I have made a mistake and did a commit with description "commit".
It is a repository for my semestral project and teacher also evaluate score for git structure and commit messages. He told me that I can solve this issue somehow without using force. He said that I suppose to merge the commits but I didn't really get how to do it. I have tried to do it using `git rebase -i HEAD~1`, but it doesn`t work and still need to be force pushed. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: If you are going to edit the commit somehow, then you will create a _new_ **different** commit and you will **have to** force-push to remove the _old_ commit **from the branch that you mean**, there is no way around it.

Comment: Without a diagram showing the structure in question along with a clear statement of the requirements and limitations, it is impossible to help. But basically if you are required to keep the same branch name and you are trying to edit the history of that branch in any way (including changing its "description"), there is no way to do that without using force push later. If you are allowed to use a _totally different branch name_ then yes, you can easily do this by interactive rebasing.

Comment: If creating new branch is allowed (i believe it is) you can do it based on the same commit you did for your original branch, then merge original into new one with `--squash` option, commit  properly, voila. Then delete original branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear as written because if you cannot force push any branches at all in your Git repository, then that seems to conflict with your teacher's statement of "He told me that I can solve this issue somehow without using force." As you've already witnessed you *must* force push in order to remove a commit from a remote branch.

That being said, this ends up being the answer regardless of what you can do in your repo, and what your teacher actually said:

The only way to remove a commit from a branch is to rewrite the branch. If you already pushed that branch, than you must do one of the following:

1. Force push the branch.
2. Delete the remote branch and re-push it. Note that deleting a remote branch is technically force pushing it, so this is essentially the same thing. But you can accomplish this without using the word "force" if you wish to describe it this way.
3. Push your rewritten branch to a different remote branch name. If you can't delete the old branch, then it will just sit out there unused.

Note that in many repos it is common to have certain shared branches locked down so that no one can force push to those specific branches, but still can force push to personal in-progress branches. The repo you're working on may not have that capability, and typically if you cannot force push a personal branch, then you probably can't delete it either, even if temporarily.

**Side Note:** You also mentioned:

> He said that I suppose to merge the commits but I didn't really get how to do it.

If you already pushed the commit with the subject "commit", there isn't any trick you can do locally with merge that will prevent you from having to choose one of the 3 options above. Perhaps your teacher didn't realize you already pushed the commit you wish to rewrite.